# DocuSign composite templates API returns 400 bad request TAB_PAGENUMBER_IS_NOT_IN_DOCUMENT

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusign-sdk

#### Context

I use DocuSign composite templates model to create envelope. and I have created a server template with a PDF document having 10 pages. And each page has an `initial` tab.

#### Issue

When I create envelope using a PDF Document with 9 pages, DocuSign raise an error

```
{
  "errorCode":"TAB_PAGENUMBER_IS_NOT_IN_DOCUMENT",
  "message":"The pagenumber specified in the tab element is not in 
             the document that the tab refers to. Tab on Page 10 of 
             Document 1 for Recipient 1"
}
```

I can solve this issue temporarily by removing the tab on page 10 in the server template. However, I don't think this is a good and long-term solution since I have other PDF documents with different number of pages.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

#### Side Notes

This issue doesn't occur if I apply template through DocuSign UI.

For example,

1. click on "sent envelope" on DocuSign UI
2. upload a PDF document with 9 page
3. apply a template which is created with a PDF document having 10 pages, and each page has an initial tab

The template can be applied without any issue through DocuSign UI.

Comment: Can you use different tab placement? meaning use anchor strings and "auto place" so you don't have to specify page numbers at all?

Comment: The problem may be the way pages are counted is different after a document is uploaded to DocuSign, the concept of "page" is not always the same for every document. DocuSign converts your document to PDF and it may impact page numbers.